# Read next record?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, record

We are on MS SQL-Server 2012.Users want to know if the time of the patients next admission date is less than 30 days for any reason.  Doesn’t have to be seen by same provider

I am not sure how to read the next record, if the MRN ID is the same, then calculate the difference in days between the record you are on and the next next record.

**For example:**

```
Record 1 : MRNID =33 Discharge date = 1/1/2016  
Record 2 : MRNID = 33 Admission date = 2/2/2016
```

MRNIDs are the same, so I calculate. Then I compare record 2 to record 3 and do the same process.

Comment: Check out the LEAD function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Use Lead() window function

```
select mrnid, 
       admission_date, 
       discharge_date, 
       lead(admission_date) over (partition by mrnid order by admission_date) next_date
  from table;
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
mnrid   admission_date  lead(admission_date)
33  2016-01-01  2016-01-02
33  2016-01-02  2016-01-03
33  2016-01-03  2016-01-04
33  2016-01-04  null
34  2016-01-01  2016-01-02
34  2016-01-02  2016-01-03
34  2016-01-03  2016-01-04
34  2016-01-04  null
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind explaining how 'lead' works in the example?

Comment: @SQLNewbie Lead retrieves the value of next records admission_date ordered by admission_date. Whenever there's a change on mrnid (partition by) the order is re-started. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Comment: @SQLNewbie I've posted sample output to clarify

Comment: @SQLNewbie Did you finally try this approach? Did it work?